# Where are the Sounds in Minecraft stored? And how can I put them in my Texture pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Does anyone know where the sounds are stored in Minecraft Java Edition 1.8? I've decompressed the version from my .minecraft and I've even decompiled Minecraft itself with MCP but have not found the sounds. Anyone know where and how I could include them in my resource pack?

Comment: If you can't find them in the game files, there's a lot of them stored here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Category:Sound_effects

Answer (score 2):

Windows: `%AppData% \.minecraft\assets\objects`

macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/assets/objects`

Linux: `~/.minecraft/assets/objects`

I believe these are the directories where sounds are stored.

Comment: Once I’m in the objects, where do I go? All I see is a bunch of 2 digit hexadecimal folders which each in them a file with a UUID for a name, and the files seem to be filled with .lang kinda stuff?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Sound_directory

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft Java Edition. If you have done the jar version file extraction with 7zip or with file conversion, you need to add a folder in the assets file:

- do not spell sounds with a capital beginning
- use only **.ogg** files
- make the folder name plural

If these methods do not work, do research on the topic!

Comment: Sorry! This is for 1.12 and up...